# Matlab - How to plot 2 different columns of data under 1 x-axis label?

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I m trying to plot 2 different columns of excelsheet data (.xls) "Data1" & "Data2" under 1 x-axis label "Jan" to compare them side by side visually. How do i do it?

Excel Data:
[Sample Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w3DI.png)

I m trying to do something like this for just 1 x-axis label for my
[matlab boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhYwu.png)

```
`tiledlayout(1,2)

ScoreS = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
sceneOrder = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May"];
surveyData.SceneCode = categorical(surveyData.SceneCode, sceneOrder);
surveyData.SceneQuestionCompare = categorical(surveyData.SceneCode, sceneOrder);

% Left axes
ax1 = nexttile
boxchart(surveyData.SceneCode, surveyData.Data1);
xlabel(ax1,'Scenes 1~12')
yt = get(gca, 'YTick');   
ytx = linspace(min(yt), max(yt), numel(ScoreS));
ytl = sprintfc('%.0f',ScoreS);   
ylabel(ax1,'Qn1 (Physical)')
legend('Physical (N=36)')

% Right axes
ax2 = nexttile
boxchart(surveyData.SceneCode, [surveyData.data3])
xlabel(ax2,'Scenes 1~12')
yt = get(gca, 'YTick');                                                         % Get Y-Tick Values
ytx = linspace(min(yt), max(yt), numel(ScoreS));                                     % New Y-Tick Values
ytl = sprintfc('%.0f',ScoreS);                                                       % New Y-Tick Labels
set(gca, 'YTick',ytx, 'YTickLabel',ytl) 
ylabel(ax2,'Qn2 (VR)')
legend('VR (N=36)')`
```

Comment: I think the ['Position and Grouping Variables'](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boxchart.html?searchHighlight=boxchart&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#mw_236c17e8-7622-48f4-9c28-dc626e7259b0) are what you want

Comment: @magnesium, thanks for replying to my post! apparently the parameters input for this boxchart takes in (xgroupdata, ydata). So my xgroupdata currently is all the months of a year(Jan~Dec) and my ydata is actually a column from an excel spreadsheet. i wanted to put in 2 variables (2 columns of data) into the ydata but i m not sure of how to do it. The current examples listed on the link was populated from 1 data column.